# httpd https/ssl not sending certificate chain

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, httpd

I'm attempting to configure a Centos 8 (8.1.1911) VM running `httpd (apache?)` (2.4.37-21) for HTTPS/SSL on a website I am hosting internal to my lab.

My lab consists of an offline root (windows) and online intermediate (windows).

Steps followed were:

- Install ssl module with `yum install mod_ssl`
- Generate private key: `openssl genpkey -outform PEM -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out priv.key`
- Generate CSR with `openssl req -new -nodes -key priv.key -config csrconfig.txt -out cert.csr` using the config file below:

`csrconfig.txt`

```
[ req ]
default_md = sha256
prompt = no
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName = <REDACTED>
countryName = <REDACTED>
stateOrProvinceName = <REDACTED>
localityName = <REDACTED>
organizationName = <REDACTED>
[ req_ext ]
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth
basicConstraints=critical,CA:false
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[ alt_names ]
DNS.0 = <REDACTED-FQDN>
DNS.1 = <REDACTED-HOSTNAME>
IP.0 = <REDACTED-IP>
```

- Submit `cert.csr` contents to online windows intermediate ca, using "Web Server" template.
- Download base-64 encoded cert chain
- Extract each of the 3 certs (root, intermediate, web server cert) to individual files
- Concatenate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
WEB-SERVER-CERT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
INTERMEDIATE-CA-CERT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ROOT-CA-CERT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

- Created `/etc/ssl/<REDACTED>/` directory
- Into above directory I placed the pem format certificate file and key file
- Appended the following to `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`:

```
# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

- Created virtual server file under `sites-available` and sym-linked into `sites-enabled` (see directory listing and contents below):

```
[root@wiki httpd]# ls -l sites*
sites-available:
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 148 Sep 27 13:20 wiki-docs.conf

sites-enabled:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 41 Sep 22 20:40 wiki-docs.conf -> /etc/httpd/sites-available/wiki-docs.conf
```

```
[root@wiki httpd]# cat sites-available/wiki-docs.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName <REDACTED>
    ServerAlias <REDACTED>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki-docs/site
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/<REDACTED>/priv.key
</VirtualHost>
```

- Restarted httpd with `systemctl restart httpd`

I am facing the following 2 issues:

1. The site is coming up as untrusted due to apache not including the full certificate chain with the certificate via the browser, it is showing the certificate as being signed by itself? The certificate contents for both certificates (the web server and the *apparent* issuer are identical):

[image]
[image]

2. The web page being served is the vanilla `Apache HTTP Server Test Page powered by CentOS` rather than the intended file. Note that this works perfectly fine if I remove the SSL statements from the `VirtualServer` block above and switch port 443 back out for 80 (http rather than https).

Could there be an issue because I'm using a custom root ca that I've built in my lab that would not be installed onto this CentOS box as a trusted root CA? Having a hard time working out what could be causing the above issues.

Comment: For SSLchain issues, get the chain from your CA and add the directive SSLCertificateChainFile

Comment: Hi @davidgo, my understanding is that directive was deprecated in v2.4.8. Whilst still _supported_ it's better to include the chain in your certificate file itself? I have also tried that directive with both my subordinate/root certificates in it but that did not work either.

Comment: It appears you are correct - I knew the certs could all be added into 1 file, but I did not know it had been deprecated. I also didn't read your post properly to see you had done so.